# Entity Framework 4 SaveChanges Method not saving to database

Tags: entity-framework-4, savechanges

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 4 for a small database application I'm writing to keep record of downloaded files. When running the application I set a break point after the tableName.Add() method, before the .SaveChanges() method and I can see the data saved into the entity; then I have another break point after calling the .SaveChanges() method, and look into the database to find there is no record saved to it. I have found a lot of similar questions, but I have not found the solution to my particular problem. Here is the code:

```
    public void StartNewDownload(string FileID)
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

        FilesDBEntities db = new FilesDBEntities();
        int startedID = (from dr in db.tblDownloadResults
                         where dr.Value.Equals("Started")
                         select dr.ResultID).First();
        tblDownloads myDownload = new tblDownloads { FileID = FileID, StartDateTime = startTime, ResultID = startedID };
        db.tblDownloads.Add(myDownload);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you "look into the database"? Have you tried reading the entity in your app? Did it work? I have seen many cases where people where using CodeFirst and were looking at a wrong database since they changed something and CodeFirst created a new database where data was saved. If you can read what your saved in your app that it means that the data is *somewhere* saved.

Comment: Pawel, Thanks for the reply. I can see this being a potential cause. Will look into this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: You can always get the connection string using `((IObjectContext)ctx).ObjectContext).Connection.ConnectionString` which will tell you what database you are hitting.

Comment: @Pawel What the HELLL. I was also looking at the wrong db in visual studio. It was saving it in /bin directory whereas the connection string was of the db in /AppData folder & I was checking that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pawel, you guided me in the right direction. The entity had the data, but the database I was looking into did not. But after reading your comment I ran the program from Visual Studio and used Process Monitor to monitor any operations to *.sdf files. This helped finding out that upon building the solution, it would create another database file to the bin\Debug folder. I forgot the database Build Action property was set as "Content".

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to see if the entity framework has really called the database.

(The tool is not included in SQL Server Express)

Comment: Edi, thanks for your reply, and sorry for not including additional information. I'm using SQL Compact instead of SQL Express. Would SQL Profiler still be useful in this case?